# write a batch to change the path for Mapped drive

Tags: scripting, batch-file, mapped-drive

I having server folder as a mapped network drive  in workstation . 
Now the that folder is shifting to to another server so Ineed to change the path this activity I need to do at 400 workstations. so can you help me with script.

Answer (score 2):

If your old drive mapping is in O: you use this to delete it:

```
net use /d O:
```

And this to create the new one:

```
net use O: \\newserver\\newpath /PERSISTENT:YES
```

If you have to specify a username \ password:

```
net use O: \\newserver\\newpath password /USER:domain\user /PERSISTENT:YES
```

Answer (score 0):

Given drive Letter g:

```
net use g: /delete
net use g: "\\server\share"
```

It's important to use the quotes around the path, otherwise paths with spaces will not map correctly.